# Ajax for retrieving data and changing elements based on data retrieved

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, controller

This is more of an informational question, and perhaps the question is not well formatted, but I wouldn't know how to explain it any better.

I have made a controller for retrieving data from the database `[HttpGet]`, how can I use Ajax for the retrieval of the a fore mentioned data, and if successful change the color of the div?

```
  [HttpGet]
    public List<AppointmentsDT> ReturnApps()
    {
        List<AppointmentsDT> list = new List<AppointmentsDT>();

        foreach (Appointment a in db.Appointments)
        {
            AppointmentsDT a1 = new AppointmentsDT();
            a1.AppWithCompanyName = a.AppWithCompanyName;
            a1.AppTime = a.AppTime;

            list.Add(a1);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I am drawing a blank as to how to write a proper syntax of ajax that would change the color of the appropriate div based on that data it received, for example if in the database there is a company named C and time named T then div1 would change color?

Is it even possible? Is there a code sample I could use? Like I said I'm drawing a blank since I'm still learning Ajax...any advice would be helpful. TNX

Comment: You make a standard Ajax request and have your C# return JSON with the appropriate data. In the JS Ajax success callback you take the object that results from parsing that JSON and say `if (data.companyName === "C")` { `$("#div1").css("color", "blue"); }`. Or similar.

Comment: In the controller it states which data from the table I need, Is the controller okay? What would I need to include in the Ajax, url, dataType? how should I parse JSON? I understand in theory, my syntax writing is not at it's best when it comes to Ajax, i know the method should be GET but which dataType? etc.
@nnnnnn

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done C# for about five years so I'm a bit out of date on the best practices there. The JS side is straightforward and there are any number of other questions on StackOverflow, and tutorials in the wider web, e.g. [this one](http://codepedia.info/jquery-ajax-json-example-asp-net-sql-database/) (which I just found with a quick Google search and have not vetted for accuracy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `AJAX` to call an `ASP.NET Web API` and call your controller from the API function.

Your `AJAX` function can bee something like this

```
$.ajax({
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: 'GET',
      url:'api/getValues', //Your API url
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
             //Use your logic to change color code here
             },
      error: function (error) {
             alert("error");
             }
     });
```

The result inside the success function will have your desired list and you could check conditions there to manipulate your div

Comment: this is it, just 1 question in the `if` statement why can't I use &&?
since i use `if(result.Time = "9:00" && result.Company = "Laakkonen")` and it gives me the else statement, and when I use just `result.Time = "9:00"` it works great? why is that?

Comment: I found the solution regarding &&, so tnx for this ajax syntax it worked perfectly !!!! :)

Comment: glad to be able to help